# Set color of stacks of multiple stacked bars

Tags: matlab, plot

I am using stacked bars to show the amount of recorded data. The idea is the more often a value is recorded the darker the stack should be. I am able to make the first bar the way it should be but if I have multiple bars with different datasets the stacks are the same colour as the first one.

As of now my issue is that I cant choose the individual stacked bars to color them individualy.

I calculated the percentage of each stack and with that I calculated the corresponding grey colour. I did this for each dataset and made one array which holds all the information. Each row represents one dataset.

I tried to add another for loop which goes through the columns of my grauwerte array but it gives me an error.

This are the results that I get [image: 1] [image: 2] .

Instead of both being the same I need them to have one colored as in the first pic and one of them as in the sec pick.

```
%PLOT
grauwerte = [grauwerte1 ; grauwerte2];

b = bar([wertebereich; wertebereich],0.1,'stacked');
set(gca,'xticklabel', {name1; name2});
for i = 1:anzahl
     b(1,i).FaceColor = [grauwerte(2,i) grauwerte(2,i) grauwerte(2,i)];
     b(1,i).EdgeColor = 'none';
end
```

EDIT: Removed the extra code, its only the plotting part now. Dimensions of grauwerte is 2x9.

Comment: Recommended debugging: (1) check the values in `grauwerte(2,:)` and make sure they are what you expect. (2) Try setting some of the colours manually just to see what changes e.g. `b(1,3).FaceColor = [1,0,0]; b(2,1).FaceColor = [0,1,0];` etc. This might help you understand how the bars are indexed. (3) please remove all the unnecessary code, it makes your question unreadable.

Comment: Hello Dan,

the values in grauwerte are correct (1).

(2): As soon as I change b(1,x) so b(2,x) I get an error "Unrecognized property 'FaceColor' for class 'matlab.graphics.GraphicsPlaceholder'.

Error in geordnet_zwei (line 120)
b(2,3).FaceColor = [1,0,0];
 "

(3) I thought that tis helpful for people to copy and try it with the same code I used. But if you think it makes it really unreadable I will remove the extra code

Comment: If I go to the property inspector of the plot I see figure 1 which has a group of axes ( 9 total). If I click on one and change the colour it is changed for the other stacked bar too. Is it even possible to do what I wanna do?